# Automatically whitelist Postgrey for outbound email?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, dovecot, postfix

I have a mail server with Ubuntu Server 12.04, Postfix, Dovecot, and Postgrey, using MySQL (MariaDB) and managed through Postfix Admin.

I am looking for a way to automatically add outbound email recipients to the Postgrey whitelist.

Comment: Set up postgrey on port 25, configure your postfix with the submission port, voila no need to whitelist your clients. Servers will send to port 25 and get greylisted, clients will authenticate to send.. so geylisting is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgrey whitelist records besides sender's and recipient's addresses also contain sender's SMTP server IP which you don't know when sending an outbound email.